# Exponential order statistics

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ exponential random variables with parameter $\lambda$ and let $X_{(1)},...,X_{(n)}$ the order statistics of the random variables. I know that $X_{(1)}$ is  exponential with parameter $\lambda n$ my question is: Is there any other $X_{(k)}$ that is also exponentially distributed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

One way of seeing this is to look at the mean of $X_{(k)}$ which is $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{\lambda(n-j+1)}$ and the variance which is $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{\lambda^2(n-j+1)^2}$.

For an exponential random variable, the variance is the square of the mean, but that is not the case here (the variance is clearly less than the square of the mean) unless $k=1$.

Comment: One last question where can I check those formulas?